# How to combine inner join and left outer join in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have two Models `invoice` and `payments`. The relationship between them is `invoice` has_many `payments`.

I'm using the following left outer join to return all invoices that have not been paid at all:

```
result1 = Invoice.includes(:payments).where(:payments => { :id => nil })
```

I'm also interested in all invoices that have been partially paid. To return those I use an inner join:

```
result2 = Invoice.joins(:payments).group("transfers.id").having("sum(payments.amount) < invoice.amount")
```

I would now like to combine the two results, i.e. I want all Invoices that have either not been paid, or not been fully paid. I know that I could just do `result = result1 + result2`. However, this doesn't return an ActiveRecord object. Is there a way to combine those two queries in a single query?

I use Rails 4.1 and PostgreSQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're correct that you can't get ActiveRecord to generate anything other than an inner join without writing it yourself. But I wouldn't use `includes` in this context, for while it does happen to cause ActiveRecord to generate a different join, that is an "implementation detail" -- it's fundamental purpose is to *load* the associated models, which is not necessarily what you want.

In your proposed solution, I don't understand why you'd group by both `invoices.id` and `payments.id` -- that seems to defeat the purpose of grouping.

You could do something like the following, although I can't say that this seems much more Rails-ish.

```
Invoice.joins("LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.transfer_id = invoices.id")
  .select("invoices.id, SUM(payments.amount) AS total_paid")
  .group("invoices.id")
  .having("SUM(payments.amount) IS NULL OR SUM(payments.amount) < invoices.amount")
```

This will return a list of Invoice objects with only the `id` field and `total_paid` field set. If you need other fields available, add them to both the `select` statement and the the `group` statement.

Comment: I had to group by both `invoices.id` and `payments.id` because otherwise I cannot put `payevents.id IS NULL` in the HAVING clause.

Comment: Hrm. I think then that your `SUM` expression isn't doing what you expect -- have you tried testing the scenario where two payments together cover the total amount of the invoice? You intend to exclude that invoice from your query (because it has been paid in full), but I think you'll find that your query includes it.

Comment: You are right, that's a problem. Unfortunately, your solution doesn't work either. I get `ERROR:  column "total_paid" does not exist`

Comment: Whoops! It looks like I forgot a `)`. Fixed now -- please try it again.

Comment: I've already seen that typo, but that's not the problem. You just cannot use an alias from SELECT in your WHERE clause because the SELECT clause gets executed after WHERE.

Comment: I don't think it's about the order of execution necessarily, but you're correct that Postgres doesn't allow you to use the column alias in a `WHERE` or `HAVING` clause. Updating.

Comment: Okay, I think the version up now should work for you. It looks remarkably similar to your original proposal with two significant differences. First, it groups only by invoice id. Second, in the having clause, it allows for the case where the sum of the payments `IS NULL` -- a fun characteristic of ternary logic systems like SQL's is that functions that are passed `NULL` inputs typically return `NULL`. That covers the case where there have been no payments for an invoice.

Comment: Great, it works now .`"SUM(payments.amount) IS NULL` was the part I couldn't figure out by myself. I was only thinking about `pamyents.id IS NULL`

Comment: Cool! One more improvement to consider: use the [COALESCE function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN12663) to write a more compact `HAVING` clause: '"COALESCE(SUM(payments.amount), 0) < invoices.amount"'. This essentially substitutes 0 for NULL so you can handle both cases in one expression, eliminating the `OR`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing just a LEFT OUTER JOIN. However, Rails doesn't seem to support `group` and `having` with the LEFT OUTER JOIN generated by `includes()`. Therefore, i had to construct the join manually which actually doesn't feel like "the Rails way".

My query:

```
    Invoice.joins("LEFT JOIN payments ON payments.transfer_id = invoices.id").group("invoices.id, payments.id").having("((payments.id IS NULL) OR (sum(payments.amount) < invoices.amount))")
```

**Update**: This doesn't work as expected. Please see the accepted answer.